# What are all the known physical conjugate pairs?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, observables

According to the uncertainty principle, certain pairs of physical quantities are complementary variables.

[Wikipedia has a list:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables#Derivatives_of_action)

- Energy <> Time
- Linear Momentum <> Position
- Angular Momentum <> Angular Position
- Mass-Momentum <> Rapidity
- Electric Potential <> Electric Charge
- Magnetic Potential <> Electric Current
- Electric Field <> Polarization Density
- Magnetic Induction <> Magnetization
- Gravitational Potential <> Mass Density

Is this list exhaustive?  Are there any other known pairs of incompatible observables?

Comment: There is no uncertainty relation between charge and electric field, or for most of the pairs given in the list for that matter.

Comment: Note from the UP article that conjugate pairs only give you the "dull", trivial, uncertainty relations. The interesting  Robertson relations involve Lie algebras such as [angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Examples) and teach you something nontrivial.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Is that example list all the relations we know of?

Comment: Of course not. Forget about lists and appreciate the techniques.